# custom post type and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a site with numerous custom post types that are created using a class. I was considering whether it was worth creating a custom taxonomy for each custom post type to offer a way of organizing and categorizing within that custom post type *-e.g* terms and tags that only apply to that post type and not others (so keeping the vernacular separate). Would that be a sensible use of taxonomies as I've seen some quite confusing (mis)use of taxonomies its seems in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  A taxonomy is simply a way to classify objects and organize them by shared characteristics (the taxonomy).

Sounds like you have a perfect use case.

Answer (score 1):

I would base this on how many custom post types you have.  If you have too many I would look into possibly re-organizing your CPTs and re-building them.  If that is not possible and you do need a lot of taxonomies I would take it a step further and auto assign a taxonomy for each one of your custom post types but to answer your question this would be a good usage of taxonomies.

Comment: also a useful point of view there which clarifies things. I'd probably set a flag for this to build a taxonomy or not.

Comment: just curious but how many cpts are you considering as numerous?

Comment: oh nothing serious- 10 max.